# Arrange Favorite Tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Recently I mistakenly closed one of my Favorite tags.  When I added it back it appeared at the bottom of the list, but due to the ad for Career I now have to scroll down to click it.  Is there a way to arrange the order of your Favorite tags?

edit based on responses:  Please consider making it easier to re-arrange favorite tags.  Delete them all, add them back in order does not seem user friendly.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I'm not sure if this is a matter of sorting tags or of it's a layout bug.

Comment: I can't post a screen shot.  I just want to re-order the favorites in the order I want, not the order added, not sorted.

Comment: Personalized sorting seems to be unnecessary. However, a simple alphabetic sort will help user visually locate tags faster.

Comment: @rwong  I can find them just fine, and don't want them sorted.

Answer (score 2):

This has come up a few times on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

[Ability to sort/reorder interesting/ignored tags in sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar)
[Sort interested/ignored tags alphabetically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/sort-interested-ignored-tags-alphabetically)

and this request to "lock" the tags so you can't accidentally delete one:

[option to lock "interesting tags" section so 'x' isn't hit accidentally on a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/option-to-lock-interesting-tags-section-so-x-isnt-hit-accidentally-on-a-tag)

None of them are marked [status-declined] so the team will be open to implementing them if they think there's enough demand. Head over to MSO and up-vote these questions and make it clear you support them in other ways. I understand feature requests are looked at in order of votes.